# Knockout binding default value of custom select list

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I've been working with knockout bindings for a couple of days and I've defined a select as below:

```
<select data-bind="options: availableLanguages, value: selectedLanguage, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'Id'"></select>
```

I receive the language list (`availableLanguages`) and the default language (`selectedLanguage`) from:

```
internal class AvailableLanguages
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }


AvailableLanguages userLanguage = new AvailableLanguages();
List<AvailableLanguages> languagesList = new List<AvailableLanguages>();

languagesList.Add(new AvailableLanguages()
                            {
                                Name = "English",
                                Id = "en"
                            });
languagesList.Add(new AvailableLanguages()
                            {
                                Name = "Francais",
                                Id = "fr"
                            });
languagesList.Add(new AvailableLanguages()
                            {
                                Name = "Espanol",
                                Id = "es"
                            });
languagesList.Add(new AvailableLanguages()
                            {
                                Name = "Italian",
                                Id = "it"
                            });

languagesList.Add(new AvailableLanguages()
                            {
                                Name = "Espanol",
                                Id = "es"
                            });

userLanguage.Id = "en";
userLanguage.Name = "English";
```

and I fill the knockout observable:

```
_mVM.availableLanguages = ko.observableArray();
_mVM.selectedLanguage = ko.observable();

_mVM.availableLanguages(languagesList);
_mVM.selectedUnit(userLanguage);
```

I managed to display only the Names from `availableLanguages` but I need the default language to be Espanol but is always the first language from the list, in my case English.

It is possible to change the default language to Espanol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the value for `selectedLanguage` after `_mVM.availableLanguages(languagesList);`

```
selectedLanguage("es");
```

Comment: The idea is because the default is coming from the database it can change so I don't think that selecting the default language this way is the best.

Comment: @Dana, where you store the default language does not really matter. You need to have that defaultLang in your client. And you also need to call seledtedLanguage(defaultLang) anyway.